# Couch shocks everything!

Tags: electrostatics

How do I get rid of the static charge I get from my microfiber couches? Every time I get up and touch something it zaps me...
I'm mostly worried about my laptop getting fried.

Comment: Tape a grouding wire to yourself and drag it around :-)

Comment: Maybe you can put a key in your pocket, and use it to release the charge on your hand before you touch anything ;-)

Comment: This is rather a pop sci question, but I think I'll leave it open, since the answer is pretty decent.

Comment: @HWLau I try to do that getting out of a car, but you have to touch the key to something grounded.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you get shocked is the following:

- As you move on the couch some static charge accumulates on your clothes and the couch
- As you stand up, the charges are separated, increasing the electric potential (the voltage) between you and the couch
- As soon as this voltage is high enough, a spark occurs

How to avoid it:

1. Wear clothes that do not favour this static accumulation: for example cotton
2. Alternatively, while you stand up, touch something conductive and grounded (or at worst, keep one hand on the sofa). This will allow you to discharge as the voltage increases, without shocks.

Comment: Good, intuitive answer here.